# How do eureka client registers itself on eureka server in Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

In Spring boot service has @EnableDiscoveryClient annotation, but we do not specify on which port Eureka server is running. so how does service figure out on which port Eureka server is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default url is `http://localhost:8761/` (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientConfigBean.java#L49)

If eureka is not available on that address then it will use the `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone` property for the fallback address. (for example `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/`)

More info: [spring-cloud-netflix docs](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/bbac5a730f673f55f0ff86cb5f94fa21aecf135c/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-netflix.adoc#registering-with-eureka)